# How to add new setting field in Fluent Form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, hook

I am working on WordPress project in which I have installed Fluent Forms plugin.
Now, I want to add new setting field in Fluent Form setting.
I want to add checkbox here : https://prnt.sc/v-BGmi2u8gNR
or anywhere in Form Setting page.
For that
I am using following hook, but it is not working.

```
add_filter( 'fluentform_form_settings_menu', array( __CLASS__, 'action__fluentform_form_settings_menu' ), 10, 2 );
public static function action__fluentform_form_settings_menu( $settingsMenus,  $form_id ) { 
    $settingsMenus['other'] = [
        'title' => __('Other Settings', 'fluentform'),
        'slug' => 'form_settings',
        'hash' => 'other',
        'route' => '/other',
        ];
   return $settingsMenus;
}
```

[image]

**EDIT 1 :**
Also I tried this hook `fluentform_create_default_settings` ,
but no luck :(

Reference from - [Fluent Form Doc](https://fluentforms.com/docs/fluentform_create_default_settings/)